# Windows explorer (Windows 10) system paths

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am looking for a list of "adresses" that you can use in the Explorer adress bar like "Shell:system" 
I know that there are lists for all "Shell:something" adresses, but i am looking for a link to the hosts file in particular and haven´t been able to find any other than the Default ones

```
 * shell:Start Menu
 * shell:Common AppData
 * shell:PhotoAlbums
 * shell:ConnectionsFolder
 * shell:Administrative Tools
 * shell:PrintersFolder
 * shell:Default Gadgets
 * shell:ProgramFilesX86
 * shell:Searches
 * shell:Common Startup
 * shell:ControlPanelFolder
 * shell:SampleVideos
 * shell:SendTo
 * shell:ResourceDir
 * shell:ProgramFiles
 * shell:CredentialManager
 * shell:PrintHood
 * shell:MAPIFolder
 * shell:CD Burning
 * shell:AppUpdatesFolder
 * shell:Common Start Menu
 * shell:LocalAppDataLow
 * shell:Templates
 * shell:Gadgets
 * shell:Programs
 * shell:Recent
 * shell:SampleMusic
 * shell:Desktop
 * shell:CommonPictures
 * shell:RecycleBinFolder
 * shell:CryptoKeys
 * shell:Common Templates
 * shell:Startup
 * shell:Links
 * shell:OEM Links
 * shell:SamplePictures
 * shell:Common Desktop
 * shell:NetHood
 * shell:Games
 * shell:Common Administrative Tools
 * shell:NetworkPlacesFolder
 * shell:SystemX86
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You can find a complete list of these "shell:"s on your system in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions`. (Very related: [Answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32417862).) There's such a complete list of "shell:"-commands which provides many more than there are in your list. Unfortunately, I didn't see one that helps with the hosts file. Of course, you can always navigate in the address bar with plain old environment variables as `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` which works, but doesn't exactly answer your question I guess.